# If CancellationToken is a struct and is passed by Value, how is it updated?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I see that CancellationToken is a struct
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netframework-4.7.1

If I pass a struct to a new function by value, it shouldn't be modified in the caller. So if i'm passing a CancellationTokenSource (by value), then I call cts.cancel(), how does the method that has a **copy** of that token is notified that it has been canceled? Shouldn't it work only if we pass by reference?

For example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    SomeCancellableOperation(cts.Token);
    cts.cancel();
}

public void SomeCancellableOperation(CancellationToken token) {
...
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
...
}
```

Comment: Each CancellationToken knows its CancellationTokenSource (the reference)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can look at the source code for [CancellationToken](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs,36b17ded8b1a228c). The basic idea is that the token only stores a reference to a CancellationTokenSource.

```
internal CancellationToken(CancellationTokenSource source)
{
    m_source = source;
}
```

The CancellationTokenSource is what is modified when it is cancelled. Checking whether the token is cancelled really just goes back to the source:

```
public bool IsCancellationRequested 
{
    get
    {
        return m_source != null && m_source.IsCancellationRequested;
    }
}
```

Comment: But isn't this reference on the `CancellationToken` reset when the token is copied? Aren't all fields on the struct reset?

Comment: @silkfire No, when a struct is copied all its fields are copied. Since CancellationTokenSource is a reference type, when the field is copied it still points to the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

The struct  is passed by value, but it contains a reference to a WaitHandle. The WaitHandle is global.